# Differentiable only at $x=0$ and $f'(0)>0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there a function $f$ satisfy

(1) Only differentiable at $x=0$

(2) $f'(0)>0$

but $f$ is not increasing state on $x=0$?

Comment: What do you mean by "$f$ is not increasing state on $x=0$"?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy there does not exist positive real number h such that satisfy f(-h) < f(0)< f(h)

Comment: @user197137 did you mean that $f''(0)$ isn't $> 0$?

Comment: @Yes.. If that condition is equivalent

Comment: @user197137 for the function to have positive derivative, such h should exist.

Comment: @Anixx I think so too.. but my friend gave me the question so i just wonder there is a trick...

Comment: Perhaps $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational, $f(x)=\arctan x$ if $x$ is irrational.

Comment: @user197137 the definition of derivative is $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$. If it is positive, then there are infinitely many such h that $f(-h) < f(0)< f(h)$

Comment: The example of David Mitra satisfies the first two conditions.

Comment: @Anixx Yes.. I think my friend just gave me for fun... The definition of a derivative says that satisfying the last condition is impossible..